# How to access Angularjs $scope in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/altermind/yak10smq/1/

I need to declare variable 'appetite' in the controller 'EntrynewCtrl', then pass it to the javascript function, something like that:

```
  <script>
    var a = appetite;
    </script>
```

When I do "console.dir(scope);" I see in console:

```
$$childScopeClass
```

I can allocate that variable via console, but have no idea how to access it in the script.

UPD: gave wrong fiddle, now it's correct

Comment: Why do you want to do this? what do you want to accomplish in doing this?

Comment: I'm building the web app with Angularjs. For certain tasks I need JSXGraph library. Get variables from mongodb with controller and pass those to the script. I guess the proper way will be to build separate directive for JSXGraph library, but right now I need very quick solution for the prototype.

Comment: @altermind What's the problem though? In your fiddle it looks like you're able to grab the scope. If there's a property on it called `appetite` and you want to access it, wouldn't it just be `var a = scope.appetite;`?

Comment: @AnthonyChu I can view $$childScopeClass (in console with console.dir(scope)), and I can clearly see 'appetite' variable there, but cannot access it for some reason.

Comment: Seems to work? http://jsfiddle.net/rxtqm994/

Comment: @AnthonyChu it does work, indeed. But for some reason when I try to implement it in my app it shows me this: `undefined` for variable, and for the scope - 
`$$childScopeClass {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $$listeners: Object…}
 `

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this,**

```
angular.element('#YOUR-ELEMENT-SELECTOR').scope().$apply(function(scope){
  scope.doStuff();
});
```

**Another way,**

```
angular.element('.ng-scope').each(function(e, t){  
    console.log(t,angular.element(t).scope());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need this tool [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) 
read this blog for more detail [Debugging AngularJS Apps from the Console](http://ionicframework.com/blog/angularjs-console/)

```
 angular.element(targetNode).scope()

-> ChildScope {$id: "005", this: ChildScope, $$listeners: Object, $$listenerCount: Object, $parent: Scope…}

angular.element(targetNode).isolateScope()

-> Scope {$id: "009", $$childTail: ChildScope, $$childHead: ChildScope, $$prevSibling: ChildScope, $$nextSibling: Scope…}
```